# jQuery: applying plugin using a string

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i wrote a jquery plugin which i'm applying like this:

```
div.myPlugin1();
```

now i want to apply it dynamically using a string:

```
var number = 1;
var plugin_name = "myPlugin"+number;
div[plugin_name]();
```

too bad this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
div[plugin_name].call(div);
```

or

```
div[plugin_name].apply(div);
```

(they differ in the way they use parameters, but behave the same for no-parameter methods)

Comment: oops, check your answer `;-)` You've doubled up.

Comment: Yeah, written the same thing twice.

Comment: Doh... meant to say `apply`. Thanks.

Comment: I always get confused by the first argument - is it needed?  Rather, when is it needed?  I understand what it's supposed to do (specify the target object of the function call).

Comment: Oops, right - saw your comment on my now-deleted answer because yours is correct, and better.  +1 and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Madbreaks: The first argument is assigned to `this` inside the function.